# kworker 100% cpu on 1 core only

Tags: 16.04

I just purchased a new Asus G752VT and installed Ubuntu 16.04.4 on it. I have observed several issues but one issue which is immediately caught my attention is that the kworker process is taking up 100% cpu, and that too on only one core.

Please help. If any commands need to be executed to gather reports i will do so.

Comment: If you can copy and paste the screen showing 100% CPU that is often helpful to others.

Comment: How do I attach an image or a file? I can do both.